# Rebuild project with helm

Tags: build, openshift, kubernetes-helm

Unable to start build pods for helm project with helm

I am wondering what is the best way to rebuild pods in a helm project on openshift. I am working with java S2i images on openshift 3.10 / 3.11. After updating my Java Code in my repository I would like to start builds.

Eventually I didn't find a solution to solve this problem.
For a new deployment I set a timestamp inside the metadata of the deployment config.

So my question is how to trigger new build with helm? Is there a better way as oc start build?

Comment: How do you handle your container images? Are you using pre-built images and mount your code inside? Or do you build the container images including the code?
Openshift pods are just instances running a container, so they are not "built" in that sense. Could you specify what you want to build more clearly?

Comment: Yes, I am using openshift s2i technologie and inject my code inside over bitbucket or github. I only change the ref tag and a date inside the buildconfig. A new build is not triggered. I have to trigger the build manually like oc new.build <my-base-image> or kubectl for kubernetes.( on openshift 3.xx there are no build triggers after modify buildconfig.)

Comment: Thanks for the info! Then your problem is rather about OpenShift image build triggers (with s2i), and not about pods or helm, as I understand it. Just to make the concepts clear: A container image is a definition of the application, a pod is a running container, based on such and image plus some extra configuration. You seem to try to trigger a build of an image within openshift. I don't see, how helm would fit in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information in the comments, I assume you need to set the correct trigger for your OpenShift image builds. The straight-forward approach seems to be to rebuild the image on every change in the repo. Therefore you should not explicitly state the commit in the BuildConfig and set a Webhook-Trigger from your code repo. For github, add this trigger to your BuildConfig:

```
{
  "type": "GitHub",
  "github": {
    "secret": "secret101"
  }
}
```

Set your github webhook to call `http://<openshift_api_host:port>/osapi/v1/namespaces/<namespace>/buildconfigs/<name>/webhooks/<secret>/github`

More details can be found in the documentation:
https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/dev_guide/builds.html#webhook-triggers

If you need to set the commit-ref explicitly in the BuildConfig, there is an alternative: You can add the ConfigChange-Trigger to your BuildConfig:

```
{
  "type": "ConfigChange"
}
```

But for now, according to the documentation, you need to add a new BuildConfig each time to trigger the build:

> Configuration change triggers currently only work when creating a new BuildConfig. In a future release, configuration change triggers will also be able to launch a build whenever a BuildConfig is updated.

See https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/dev_guide/builds.html#config-change-triggers

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, the ConfigChange trigger do not work because of the openshift version. Maybe on openshift 4 the feature is available. I think that the webhooks could be a good solution. At the moment I deploy a tagged master on production environment. So, if have to change the buildconfig with helm because of the ref tag in the buildconfig. With a master deployment without tagging the could work great.